# The SharedPreferences code was no function to make button Visible

Tags: java, android, boolean, sharedpreferences

First time i had done coding without preferences the button can visible but when i put preferences code the button not visible

i have 3 class it is menu.class, levelone.class, leveltwo.class

this is the following code of `menu.class` like this

```
public class menu extends Activity {

Button f1, f2;
ImageView f2lock;
boolean levelTwoUnlocked;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.famouslevel);

    f1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.f1);      
    f1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v){
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent level1 = new Intent ();
        level1.setClassName ("com.example.game", "com.example.game.levelone");
        startActivityForResult (level1, 0);              
            }             
      });       
}                 
    public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent level1) {
        super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, level1); 

        f2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.f2);      
        f2lock=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.f2lock);

        switch (resultCode) {
        case 2:   SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);        
                   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                   editor.putBoolean("f2", levelTwoUnlocked);
                   editor.commit();

    if(levelTwoUnlocked){
        f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
        }
        else {
        f2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        f2lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }      
      }
    f2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v){
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent level2 = new Intent ();
            level2.setClassName ("com.example.game", "com.example.game.leveltwo");
            startActivityForResult (level2, 0);              
            }             
      });       
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.splashscreen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

and in `levelone.class` i have put this code

```
 public void onClick(View v){
                  setResult (2);
                  finish();          
                  }
                });
```

thats code is to make button visible in `menu.class` but when `levelone.class` finish(); is nothing happen with the button, it's still GONE

f2 button function is to open `leveltwo.class` and in `leveltwo.class` had same code to set f3 button visible

```
public void onClick(View v){
                      setResult (3);
                      finish();          
                      }
                    });
```

and so on with the next level had a same code to make button visible
Did my code setResult is wrong or the preferences code make it not function?

Answer (score 0):

Int the lines:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);        
               SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
               editor.putBoolean("f2", levelTwoUnlocked);
               editor.commit();
```

You just put always false to "f2", because levelTwoUnlocked is always false.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a boolean value to `leveTwoUnloacked`
 or
make changes in

`editor.putBoolean("f2",true);`

and check

```
if(prefernces.getBoolean("f2",false))
{
//your code
}
```